# Most efficient way to get child object properties from a DirectorySearcher result in Active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, directory, ldap

I am trying to find the most efficient way possible to get properties from certain types of objects whose parent OUs have been gethered using a `DirectorySearcher` query. These object's parents are groups that users are a member of (directly or indirectly) in Active Directory.

I think I have found a good recursive solution to get these groups, however once I have my result set, I'm not sure what the most efficient way to fetch the data is. Right now I'm using each result's Path to fetch the data like I would if I was just getting a single object.

I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do this, possibly by adding to my `DirectorySeacher`'s `Filter` and getting these objects directly in my query results. The objects I'm searching for are objects so it seems the closest I can get to them in the `DirectorySearcher` query is going to be their parent OU.

```
foreach (SearchResult result in matchingADGroups)
{
    // Here I need to get result's child object properties(could be multiple children)
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + result.Path.Substring(7));

    foreach(DirectoryEntry child in entry.Children)
    {
        Shortcut shortcut = new Shortcut();
        shortcut.DisplayName = (string)child.Properties["myDisplayName"].Value;
        shortcut.Id = (string)child.Properties["myId"].Value;

        shortcuts.Add(shortcut);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm always skeptic about recursion when web requests or queries are being performed. But if it works for you, great!.
 
You can use DirectorySearcher for child nodes to further narrow down the resutls. Setup a DirectorySearcher:

```
DirectorySearcher _Search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
_Search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))";//can add more parameters
```

You can add more parameters depending on how the ActiveDirectory is set up.
Next you can specify the properties that you need in the results

```
_Search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedname");
```

Use FindAll() method to get all objects and iterate them using foreach loop:

```
foreach (var result in _Search.FindAll()){   
       //DO whatever you want here
       Shortcut shortcut = new Shortcut();
       shortcut.DisplayName = result.DisplayName;

}
```

Hope this helps.